# Any Subgroup containing commutator subgroup is normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, derived-subgroup

I can prove that commutator is minimal subgroup such that factor group of it is abelian. I had encountered one statement as

> If $H$ is a subgroup containing commutator subgroup then $H$ is
>   normal.

I.e. we have to show that $\forall g\in G$ such that $gHg^{-1}=H$ with fact that $G'\subset H$

It is for elements in $G'$ to show condition for normality.

But how to do for elements not in $G'$ but in $H$, that is in $H\setminus G'$?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746648/any-subgroup-that-contains-the-subgroup-generated-by-all-commutators-is-normal).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If $g\in G$ and $h\in H$, then $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}=h'$, for some $h'\in H$ (since $H$ contains the commutator subgroup). But then $ghg^{-1}=h'h\in H$. Therefore, $gHg^{-1}\subset H$.

Answer (score 15):

$G'$ is certainly normal in $G$, and $G/G'$ is Abelian. Every
subgroup of an Abelian group is normal. But $H/G'$ is a subgroup
of $G/G'$ so $H/G'$ is normal in $G/G'$. Therefore, by the third
isomorphism theorem for groups, $H$ is normal in $G$.